# How to know a selectonemenu is empty onLoad of the page

Tags: jsf, selectonemenu

I have a simple requirement to display an error message in the page when selectOneMenu is empty because of no data returned from the DB.

I am not seeing any appropriate listener for the selectOneMenu that can handle this.

```
<h:selectOneMenu id="product" value="#{managedList.addPList}">
    <f:selectItems value="#{managedList.pList}" />
</h:selectOneMenu>
```

If `#{managedList.pList}` is an empty list, I would like to display error message in my page.

I was hoping I would have some onLoad listener for the selectOneMenu where I can handle it.

PS: I am very new to JSF. Please let me know if the question is very broad

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please correct me if I didn't get your question correctly. You have a list in your managed bean, that you display in a `selectOneMenu`. Now you want that when this list is empty, you display instead, an error message. Am I right ?
If this is what you want, then you can do it using the `rendered` attribute of JSF UIComponents, for example:

```
<h:panelGrid id="panel" columns="1" border="0" rendered="#{empty managedList.pList}">
   Here you can put everything you want when the list is empty.

</h:panelGrid>
```

Notice that you are not restricted to using `h:panelGrid`, the rendered attribute is available for almost every component, and you can use to decide when a component will be rendered or not.
Please explain your point if this is not what you want.
Hope this helps

Comment: Bingo !! This is what exactly I wanted :)